# Upgrade Grafana in HDP 2.5

Tags: upgrade, hortonworks-data-platform, grafana, ambari

Ambari uses Grafana to display metrics. I am using external data source to view other metrics. 
I want to upgrade grafana version from 2.6 to 4.0-beta for alerting feature.
Should I

> upgrade grafana provided inside the HDP 2.5 package

or

> install new version separately?

How to do this and which method is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with installing a separate version. You can get a Grafana 3.x compatible plugin from here - https://grafana.net/plugins/praj-ams-datasource and then configure your datasource to use the HDP Cluster.

I am working on a v4.x compatible version and should have it done very soon as well.

Comment: Hi @praj thanx for the answer